# How to print spaces at end of a line with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to print only spaces in a line or at the end of a line with Python?

If I type

```
print("                   ")
```

in fact, it only output a new line without these spaces I typed.
And if I type

```
print("Hello              ")
```

there's also no spaces output at the end of line.
To check if there're ending spaces printed, I copy these outputs to both Microsoft Word and Notepad, It shows that there's no spaces at the end of output line.

Comment: Try this - `print("Hello", end=" ")`

Comment: There **is** space. To test, do: `print("Hello              ", end='#')`.

Comment: The spaces are there, you just can't see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some extra padding with `ljust`:

```
str.ljust(width, fillchar)
```

So simply use it in this way:

```
print("He" + "llo")
>> Hello

print("He".ljust(10) + "llo")
>> He        llo
```

Answer (score 0):

end=" " gives a space at the end of string

```
print("Hello",end=" ")
print("World")
```

Output for above code :

```
Hello World
```